# Error does not compile xml by <xsd:simpleType> tag

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I try to add a new list to my xml to generate some classes for a service, but when I add this xml fragment it gives me an error in the tags that are inside **xsd:sequence** all **xsd:simpleType**. This is the error message that tells me:

> s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'sequence' must match
> (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence   | any)*). A
> problem was found starting at: simpleType.

And this is how I have built the xml snippet built

```
   <xsd:complexType name="RegisterEventsSubRequestType">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="Canal" type="xsd:integer"></xsd:element>
         <xsd:element name="Ean13" type="xsd:integer"></xsd:element>
         <xsd:simpleType>
               <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                  <xsd:totalDigits value="13"/>
               </xsd:restriction>
         </xsd:simpleType>
         <xsd:element name="Center" type="xsd:integer"></xsd:element>
         <xsd:simpleType>
               <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                  <xsd:totalDigits value="4"/>
               </xsd:restriction>
         </xsd:simpleType>
         <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:dateTime"></xsd:element>
         <xsd:element name="SubColectives" type="tns:SubColectivesType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

What is the error due to? How could I solve it? I thought that adding a name attribute would solve it, but it hasn't let me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `sequence` cannot contain a loose `simpleType` declaration.

You probably meant to write

```
  <xsd:complexType name="RegisterEventsSubRequestType">
     <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Canal" type="xsd:integer"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Ean13">
           <xsd:simpleType>
                 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                    <xsd:totalDigits value="13"/>
                 </xsd:restriction>
           </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Center">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                     <xsd:totalDigits value="4"/>
                  </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:dateTime"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="SubColectives" type="tns:SubColectivesType"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: But you remove the integer type from the EAN13 element tag, right?

Comment: @Wail Yes, because `ean13` is either a `type="xsd:integer"` or an instance of that simple type that restricts `base="xsd:integer"` to values with a length of 13 characters. It cannot be both at the same time.